# jQuery: changing each <p> in each <div> depending on if/else result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, conditional-statements

In my HTML I have a gallery in which each gallery item has the following format:

```
<div class="gallery-img">
     <a href="#" target="_blank">
         <img src="#" />
     </a>
     <p class="imgDescription">November 20th</p>
     <span class="hidden">20141120</span>
</div>
```

I'm currently attempting to build a function which will allocate a differing string to each .imgDescription depending on what the difference is between the hidden `<span>` and an external `today` variable which holds the current date. Here's the JS/jQuery:

```
today = yyyy+mm+dd;

$('.gallery-img').each(function() {
    var itemRelease = $('.gallery-img span');
    var timeToRelease = itemRelease - today;

    if(timeToRelease < -1) {
        $('.imgDescription').val(timeToRelease + " " + "days ago.");
    } else if(timeToRelease > +1) {
        $(this).val("In" + " " + timeToRelease + " " + "days");
    } else if(timeToRelease === -1) {
        $(this).val("Released yesterday");
    } else if(timeToRelease === 1) {
        $(this).val("Releases tomorrow");
    } else if(timeToRelease === 0) {
        $(this).val("Releases today!");
    }
});
```

How would I go about in getting jQuery to compare each `<div>`'s `<span>` value and then inserting the resulting case into the respective .imgDescription?

The contents of the `today` variable are defined earlier in the code.
I used if/else rather than a switch, as a previous thread indicated a switch would be 30x slower.

Completely stuck on this! Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should compare each of `.gallery-img`

```
// wrap in document ready
$(function() {

var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = (today.getMonth()+1) * 100; //January is 0! *100 to form single number
var yyyy = today.getFullYear() * 10000; // *10000 to form single number

today = yyyy+mm+dd;
var todayString = today.toString();

$('.gallery-img').each(function() {

    var $this = $(this); 
    var itemRelease = $this.find('span');
    var imgDescription = $this.find('.imgDescription');
    var timeToRelease = campareDate(toDate(todayString), toDate(itemRelease.text()));

    console.log(timeToRelease);

    if(timeToRelease > 1) {
        imgDescription.text(timeToRelease + " " + "days ago.");
    } else if(timeToRelease < -1) {
        imgDescription.text("In" + " " + -timeToRelease + " " + "days");
    } else if(timeToRelease === 1) {
        imgDescription.text("Released yesterday");
    } else if(timeToRelease === -1) {
        imgDescription.text("Releases tomorrow");
    } else if(timeToRelease === 0) {
        imgDescription.text("Releases today!");
    }
});

});

function toDate(str) {
    return new Date(str.substr(0,4) + '-' + str.substr(4, 2) + '-' + str.substr(6, 2));
}

function campareDate(date1, date2) {
    return Math.floor((date1 - date2) / (86400 * 1000));
}
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/70nzrgxy/1/

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer! All issues fixed, just had to invert the conditionals to make the output behave correctly (it was putting "In 10 days" when it should have been "10 days ago")

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit of a mess. So i fixed a few bugs here and there.

`<div class="gallery-img">
            <a href="#" target="_blank">
                <img src="#" />
            </a>
            <p class="imgDescription" release-date="2014-11-20">November 20th</p>
        </div>`

Removed span, i guess You don't need this since is hidden.

`$('.gallery-img').each(function() {
    var itemRelease = $(this).find('p').attr('release-date');
    var itemReleaseDate = new Date(itemRelease);
    var timeToRelease = dateDiff(today,itemReleaseDate);
    if(timeToRelease < -1) {
        $(this).find('p').text(timeToRelease + " " + "days ago.");
    } else if(timeToRelease > 1) {
        $(this).find('p').text("In" + " " + timeToRelease + " " + "days");
    } else if(timeToRelease === -1) {
        $(this).find('p').text("Released yesterday");
    } else if(timeToRelease === 1) {
        $(this).find('p').text("Releases tomorrow");
    } else if(timeToRelease === 0) {
        $(this).find('p').text("Releases today!");
    }
});`

Added a timediff function. If you have a questions, go ahead and ask.

http://jsfiddle.net/b3rfe4ty/

Answer (score 0):

You want to output your strings to your `.imgDescription`?

```
 $('.gallery-img').each(function() {

     // do what you need...
     $(this).find('.imgDescription').html("Description you want");
 }
```